# Icon desktop to launch a python script with a click (Ubuntu) problems

Tags: python, ubuntu, icons, desktop-application, launcher

I'd like to launch a python script using an icon desktop.
I implemented the file .desktop as:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=testGUI
Version=1.0
Icon=/home/mypc/Desktop/test/testimg.xpm
Path=/home/mypc/Desktop/test/
Exec=python /home/mypc/Desktop/test/testGUI.py
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Type=Application
```

The icon appears on my Ubuntu desktop but, when I click, it doesn't launch the GUI, nothing.

What's the problem? I tried everythings.

Thank you

Comment: Do you use the GNOME desktop environment?

Comment: Have you right-clicked on your python file testGUI.py and in the permissions tab allowed the file to run as a program ?

Comment: Yes, I have GNOME and I allowed the file to run as a program

Comment: Did you do the same with the .desktop file you created to run as a program?

Comment: unfortunately not. when I click, it doesn't run...anything

Comment: I wasn't clear. You have to also give permissions to the .desktop file (right click, permissions tab, allow to run as a program).

Comment: Yes I have done this but nothing. It seems that It can't execute the command, so impossible to open de .py that has the GUI inside

Comment: [Solved]: Probably it was a problem related to the Python environment...so I wrote python3 (not python) and it ran!